# Bitbucket pull request add rebuild button

Tags: build, bitbucket, bamboo, pull-request, rebuild

I have a bamboo branch plan that is start to build when a pull request is created,
what i want to do is to add a rebuild button to action menu in bitbucket pull request that allow me to restart the build in case of this build is failed like it is shown on this following picture

[image: bitbucket]

I have seen that in the past with jenkins but i don't know how to do it in Bamboo

Help please